# How to install phpbb in openshift online starter

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

How to install phpbb in opensift online starter. Because starter has only 1 gb space and mysql itself needs 1 gb how to install php and mysql. Here is the link to phpbb. https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/phpbb-example Please give step by step command for openshift console. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a bit more complicated in OpenShift Online Starter if your front end requires its own persistent storage because Starter only provides you with one persistent volume and it isn't possible to mount a persistent volume on separate MySQL and PHP applications at the same time. This is separate to the issue you suggest of needing 1GB for the database and a separate 1GB for PHP. If they can share a 1GB persistent volume, it is possible to do, but is going to require a different approach to the normal way you would setup the applications if done separately.

So first question before can proceed to describe any possible solution, is whether you can survive with having both phpbb local data and the database itself in one shared 1GB persistent volume?

Comment: I can survive with 1gb, please give step by step commands for oc

Comment: Without me sitting down for a few hours or more to come up with a new quickstart the process will be a bit of trial and error. StackOverflow is not a good forum for back and forth discussions. So if you can send a message to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openshift then we can continue the discussion there.